# how to use Analytic functions instead of join with itself

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to find the credit/debit side of a transaction in a table like this.

```
with t1 as
(select 1 v, 11 t, 100 amnt from dual
 union
 select 1 v, 12 t, 200 amnt from dual
 union
 select 1 v, 13 t, -100 amnt from dual
 union
 select 1 v, 14 t, -200 amnt from dual
)
select * from t1
```

in this table, there is a transaction with 4 articles. 11 receives 100$ from 13 and 12 receives 200$ from 14.
one solution is join t1 with itself. this is heavy when the records are very much, like 100 million records per day. the problem in joining this table with itself is heavy process time.
i am looking for a solution with Analytic functions to find the sender or receiver of a article.
Can you give a solution for reaching this goal.

Thanks.

Comment: `sql` tag info contain a clear and simplify version about how to ask a good `sql` question. please read it first and follow the guideline to improve your question [here-is-link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info).

Comment: @user2352554 . . . Without an indication of what rows belong to what transaction, you cannot do what you want -- particularly in a large table.  After all, the amounts in your example could all be `100`/`-100` -- and there would be no way of knowing which should be combined with which.

Answer (score 0):

If this sample T1 table represents data you really have, it is **less than obvious** that 11 receives 100$ from 13. **Nothing** but your words suggests that. Therefore, if you want to make it "obvious" and "faster", add another column which explicitly says that, makes a referential integrity constraint (possible within the same table; why not?), create additional table with pairs of "who received what from whom", or whatever else so that you wouldn't have to write queries which suffer from a wrong data model.

Comment: thanks for your comment. the table structure is the same and we cannot change that.

Comment: Then you have a problem (and you're aware of that). How do you know that 12 didn't receive 100 from 13?

Comment: the amount should be same

Comment: Ideally, probably so. In real life, that's not always the case. If invoice says you have to pay 53.000$ and you pay it in two transactions: 30.000 + 23.000, you can't match 53.000 to neither of these, but everything seems to be fine because 30.000 + 23.000 = 53.000.

Comment: yes.your right. you suppose there is not such  a condition.

Comment: Furthermore, what if - for both T = 11 and 12 - amount values were 100 (which means that for 13 and 14 amounts were -100). How will you then know which matches which?